Additional line created when using equations in algorithm2e
Consider the following example, placing equation*s inside of an algorithm environment:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\LinesNumbered

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  \ForEach{first loop} {
    \begin{equation*}
      a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    \end{equation*}
    After \;
    After \;
    After \;
  }
  \ForEach{second loop} {
    Before
    \begin{equation*}
      a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    \end{equation*}
    After \;
    After \;
    After \;
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}


This produces the following output:

The problem is the spacing of the equations. Specifically, in line 2 we see that a lot of vertical space is added, where none is required. Indeed, line 7 shows that it is possible to add some text before the equation starts within the blank space left in the layout. What is more, the line number 2 is above of the equation rather than aligned with it.
Is there a way to make the equations behave more naturally and avoid the introduction of the additional space?

Quick hack:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\LinesNumbered

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  \ForEach{first loop} {
    \parbox{\hsize}{%
      \[
      a^2 + b^2 = c^2
      \]
    }\par
    After \;
    After \;
    After \;
  }
  \ForEach{second loop} {
    Before\par
    \parbox{\hsize}{%
      \[
      a^2 + b^2 = c^2
      \]
    }\par
    After \;
    After \;
    After \;
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}



Well, yes. But this is going to fail e.g. for deeper loops, right? We would need to know the remaining / used up width, right?

@hfhc2 See my updated answer

Great, appreciate the help :)

I'd define a specific environment.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{algoequation}{b}{%
  \par\makebox[\dimeval{\hsize}]{$\displaystyle#1$}\par
}{}


\LinesNumbered

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  \ForEach{first loop} {
    \begin{algoequation}
      a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    \end{algoequation}
    After \;
    After \;
    After \;
  }
  \ForEach{second loop} {
    Before
    \begin{algoequation}
      a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    \end{algoequation}
    After \;
    After \;
    After \;
  }

\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}


With a simple change, you can get fixed indentation instead:
\NewDocumentEnvironment{algoequation}{b}{%
  \par\hspace*{\algomargin}$\displaystyle#1$\par
}{}


This is why defining a specific environment is recommended: you're not tied to a particular representation and you can easily modify the definition, but not the document code.
Side note. Please, don't use standalone for such examples.
